# Why does the Iterator.next() method of ArrayList copy the elementData field?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Here is the source code of the `next()` method in the `Iterator` provided by [`ArrayList.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator--):

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    // Why copy the entire elementData from the outer ArrayList class?
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;

    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

Why does this code from the JDK try to copy the entire data array `elementData` into the inner class iterator, since the inner class has access to the fields in the outer class? That will be really expensive for a huge list.

I know there must be an explanation behind this code - what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why JDK try to copy the entire data array into the inner class iterator. That will be really expensive for a huge list.

No, it isn't.  It copies the *reference* to the array, not the array itself.  That is always O(1); not expensive at all.

`elementData` would normally have to be accessed as `Itr.outerClass.elementData`, with `outerClass` being the implicit reference the inner class carries to the outer, so this change reduces the number of indirections and references that get followed (by a tiny amount, but it's *iterating over an `ArrayList`,* it's one of the most common operations ever).

Comment: you are right. but why that operation? they also check the length of elementData again.

Comment: @weiShen, like I said, it means that instead of doing `Itr.outerClass.elementData` twice, they look it up once and then can use it directly, saving the extra dereference of `Itr.outerClass`.

Comment: It's perhaps for the saving on `getField` (remember, `next` is expected to be called quite a few times).

Comment: @weiShen The local reference can not be changed by another thread while execution the following code. If ```ArrayList.this.elementData``` was changes between the range check and the return, there might be an out of bounds error.

Comment: @JornVernee I'm not sure I find that argument convincing; ArrayList isn't intended to be thread-safe.

Comment: I think the reason is same as the reason for why `String#hashCode()` does: `char val[] = value;` (getting a reference copied in the local variable). IOW, @LouisWasserman is right ;)

Comment: @JornVernee CME is actually lot more cryptically named choice in the absence of multiple threads. But all of that has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but the `Itr.outerClass.elementData` is only call once by  `return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];`, not twice?

Comment: @weiShen it's referenced once in `elementData.length` and a second time in the `return` statement.

Comment: @weiShen, what?  This has nothing to do with `ConcurrentModificationException`.  This is a tiny microoptimization and has nothing particularly to do with threads.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  thx for yr prompt response! now I understand:)